# I am trying to load a JSON file to be used in a D3 plus visualization using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, d3plus

I am trying to create a boxplot by using D3plus and uploading/storing JSON data into a variable with jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head> 
    <script src="./JS/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./JS/d3plus.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./JS/jQuery.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

<div id="viz"></div>

<script>
  var data;

  $.getJSON("./Data/boxplot.json", function(json) {
      data = json;
  });
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")
    .data(data)
    .type("box")
    .id("name")
    .x("building")
    .y("total")
    .time(false)
    .height(800)
    .ui([{ 
        "label": "Visualization Type",
        "method": "type", 
        "value": ["scatter","box"]
      }])
    .draw()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I copy-and-past the json data into the file, it works. However, when I try to fetch the data from an external json file stored in a folder "Data", it doesn't work. I get the error: "Box Plot visualizations require setting the "data" method".

Here is my file structure:

[image]

Here is my json file:

```
[{"building":"MMB","name":"Shane","total":1},{"building":"MMB","name":"Geneviève, Bérubé","total":1},{"building":"MMB","name":"Dana","total":10},{"building":"MMB","name":"karine","total":2},{"building":"MMB","name":"Anthony","total":1},{"building":"MMB","name":"Erwin","total":6},{"building":"MMB","name":"Jake","total":2},
{"building":"MMB","name":"Karen","total":1},{"building":"MMB","name":"sabrina","total":2},{"building":"MMB","name":"Jeannine","total":4}]
```

Thank you very much for your time!

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head> 
    <script src="./JS/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./JS/d3plus.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./JS/jQuery.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

<div id="viz"></div>

<script>

 $.getJSON("./Data/boxplot.json", function(json) {
  data = json,
  success = function(data){
    .container("#viz")
    .data(data)
        .type("box")
        .id("name")
        .x("building")
        .y("total")
        .time(false)
        .height(800)
        .ui([{ 
            "label": "Visualization Type",
            "method": "type", 
            "value": ["scatter","box"]
        }])
        .draw()
  }
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: $.getJSON is asynchronous - therefore data wont be populated until after all that code after the getJSON call runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("./Data/boxplot.json", function(json) {
  data = json,
  success = function(data){
    d3plus.viz()
      .container("#viz")
      .data(data)
      .type("box")
      .id("name")
      .x("building")
      .y("total")
      .time(false)
      .height(800)
      .ui([{ 
          "label": "Visualization Type",
          "method": "type", 
          "value": ["scatter","box"]
      }])
      .draw()
   }
})
```

Something like that should work.  The value of "success" after your `getJSON` call is a function that will be called after the asynchronous response is return (thus the `data` parameter which is passed to the function).  Didn't check that the D3 stuff worked but that should solve your AJAX call problem.

Answer (score 1):

D3plus supports loading data from JSON files. Simply pass the path to the data method:

```
var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")
    .data("./Data/boxplot.json")
    .type("box")
    .id("name")
    .x("building")
    .y("total")
    .time(false)
    .height(800)
    .ui([{ 
        "label": "Visualization Type",
        "method": "type", 
        "value": ["scatter","box"]
      }])
    .draw();
```

And for reference, here are all of the custom properties that can be set for the data method: https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#data